# Is it possible to get the value of a TextView, in a RecyclerView, in which clicking the TextView another layout opens

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Basically, I am creating a messaging app. So, I created a RecyclerView in which an ArrayList of Objects(Mobile Numbers) are stored. On clicking on any of the objects, opens the layout that shows all the messages sent by the clicked Mobile number. That's why I am trying to figure out how to access the object that has been clicked.

Haven't tried anything yet. Still trying to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    int selectedPosition = position;
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

//  this is how you access the clicked Mobile number if you have stored it an array 
            String phoneNum = yourArray.get(selectedPosition).toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourNewActivity.class);
// to pass the phone number to the next activity where you can get it with getIntent()
intent.putExtra( PHONE_NUM , phoneNum);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Let me know if you have any problems in understanding the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a efficient way.
First create a interface and declare it in your adapter class..

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void itemClick(int position);
}

private ClickListener clickListener;
```

Than on onBindViewHolder call it.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clickListener.itemClick(position);
        }
    });
}
```

Now from your activity where you called the adapter implement the interface, after implement you can easily override this onClick method there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to run code when a `RecyclerView` item is clicked:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //Code to be executed
        }    
    });
}
```

Now, if you want to get a mobile number from an array, you can put the following code in the `onBindViewHolder()` function. To start a new activity, you can use `Intent`:

```
String mobileNumber = YOUR_MOBILE_NUM_ARRAY.get(POSITION_OF_ITEM_CLICKED).toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_APPLICATION_CONTEXT, YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
intent.putExtra("MOBILE_NUM", mobileNumber);
startActivity(intent);
```

Final code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String mobileNumber = YOUR_MOBILE_NUM_ARRAY.get(position).toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_APPLICATION_CONTEXT, YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
            intent.putExtra("MOBILE_NUM", mobileNumber);
            startActivity(intent);
        }    
    });
}
```

To get the mobile number in your other activity, put the following code in the `onCreate()` function:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
    String mobNum = extras.getString("MOBILE_NUM");
}
```